# How to pass data from TableView cell to another viercontroller in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass data from TableView cell to another ViewController but on the other veiwcontroller passing value found nil.
Here is the DidSelectRow code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Test") as? TestVC
    present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    vc?.Name = array_product_name[indexPath.row]
}
```

And here is the another ViewController code:

```
class TestVC: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!

var Name : String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    print("Product Name is:-\(Name)")
    nameLbl?.text = Name
}
```

Comment: `Name` variable can't be nil.

Comment: can you please give me a hint?

Comment: Is `array_product_name` an array of objects or an array of string?

Comment: array_product_name[indexPath.row].name is not helping

Comment: array_product_name array of String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first view controller code is fine. On the second one instead of setting values in `viewDidLoad` set those in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @Asifmimi have a quick look at this whenever you have time https://stackoverflow.com/tour. And you are very welcome.  :-)